# In Openpyxl - want to convert the excel cell value into a integer while copying data into csv

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am copying a csv values into excel using openpyxl.

```
  with open('file_modified.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
    next(reader, None) #skip the headers in the csv file
    i = 2 # paste into second row of the excel
  for row in reader:
        for j in range(1, len(row)):
            if(j==1 or j==10):
                ws_1.cell(row=i, column=j).value = float(row[j - 1])
                ws_1.cell(row=i, column=j).number_format = '0000000000'
            else:
                # writing the read value to destination excel file
                ws_1.cell(row=i, column=j).value = row[j-1]
        i +=1
     wb_1.save(destination_file)
```

But still when i open excel the column 1, column 10 still shows error. I need to manually go and convert it to string. Also when i open excel its throws recover error. Not sure why.
[image]

-Prasanna.K

Comment: `j` can never be **both** 1 and 10 so the condition is never fulfilled. Presumably you mean `j == 1 or j== 10`

Comment: changed it to or condition...can you please advise now

Comment: its working now